# EJB3.0 transaction fail inside a method in successive transaction taking place

Tags: ejb-3.0

I am processing three transaction inside a single method in stateless container managed bean .i want to persist three transaction while if one throws exception other two should complete their respective transaction ,error is that if first or any one is throwing exception other two are to executing please give some helpful suggestion

```
public void allocateSubjectToStudent(SubjectAllocatedToStudentDto dto)throws Exception {
            logger.info("allocateSubjectToStudent method entry :");


                List<Subject> coreList=dto.getCoreList();
                Iterator<Subject> iterator=coreList.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    logger.info("inside while :");
                    SubjectAllocatedToStudentBo bo=new SubjectAllocatedToStudentBo();
                    bo.setBacthId(dto.getBacthId());
                    bo.setSemester(dto.getSemester());
                    bo.setStudentId(dto.getStudentId());
                    Subject subject=iterator.next();
                    bo.setSubjectName(subject.getSubjectName());
                    bo.setSubjectType(subject.getAbbreviation());

                    try{
                       manager.persist(bo);
                    }
                    catch(javax.persistence.PersistenceException e){
                        Throwable t = e.getCause();
                        while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException)) {
                            t = t.getCause();
                        }//while
                        if (t instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException) {
                            throw new Exception("Core subject already allocated to student");
                        } //end of if
                    }//end of catch
                }//end of while

                List<Subject> departmentallist=dto.getDepartmentList();
                Iterator<Subject> iterator1=departmentallist.iterator();
                while(iterator1.hasNext()){

                    logger.info("inside while :");
                    SubjectAllocatedToStudentBo bo=new SubjectAllocatedToStudentBo();
                    bo.setBacthId(dto.getBacthId());
                    bo.setSemester(dto.getSemester());
                    bo.setStudentId(dto.getStudentId());
                    Subject subject=iterator1.next();
                    bo.setSubjectName(subject.getSubjectName());
                    bo.setSubjectType(subject.getAbbreviation());
                    try{
                        manager.persist(bo);
                        }
                        catch(javax.persistence.PersistenceException e){

                            Throwable t = e.getCause();
                            while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException)) {
                                t = t.getCause();
                            }//while
                            if (t instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException) {
                                throw new Exception("InterDepartmental subject already allocated to student");
                            } //end of if
                        }//end of catch
                }//end of while

                List<Subject> electiveList=dto.getElectiveList();
                Iterator<Subject> iterator2=electiveList.iterator();
                while(iterator2.hasNext()){

                    logger.info("inside while :");
                    SubjectAllocatedToStudentBo bo=new SubjectAllocatedToStudentBo();
                    bo.setBacthId(dto.getBacthId());
                    bo.setSemester(dto.getSemester());
                    bo.setStudentId(dto.getStudentId());
                    Subject subject=iterator2.next();
                    bo.setSubjectName(subject.getSubjectName());
                    bo.setSubjectType(subject.getAbbreviation());
                    try{
                        manager.persist(bo);
                        }
                        catch(javax.persistence.PersistenceException e){

                            Throwable t = e.getCause();
                            while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException)) {
                                t = t.getCause();
                            }//while
                            if (t instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException) {
                                throw new Exception("Elective subject already allocated to student");
                            } //end of if
                        }//end of catch
                }//end of while


            logger.info("allocateSubjectToStudent method exit :");

        } //end of method
```

Answer (score 1):

Within a single method invocation there is only a single transaction active. To achieve what you want, you must perform the three operations in different transactions. This would require one more level of abstracttion.

```
public class MyFreshTransaction {

  @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void updateO() {
   //do something
  }

  @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void update1() {
   //do something
  }

  @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void update2() {
   //do something
  }
}

@Stateless
public class MyTransactionProcessor {

  @EJB
  private MyFreshTransaction freshTransaction;

  public void processTransaction() {
    try {
       //The current transaction context will be suspended, and a new one invoked
       //if the new one fails and is rollback, the current one is not affected.
       //you can then handle the exception, by rethrowing the exception,in which case
       //the current transaction will also be rolled back, or continue based on your logic.
       freshTransaction.update0();
    } catch (Exception ex ) {//handle}

    try {
       //The current transaction context will be suspended, and a new one invoked
       //if the new one fails and is rollback, the current one is not affected.
       //you can then handle the exception, by rethrowing the exception,in which case
       //the current transaction will also be rolled back, or continue based on your logic.
       freshTransaction.update1();
    } catch (Exception ex ) {//handle}

    try {
       //The current transaction context will be suspended, and a new one invoked
       //if the new one fails and is rollback, the current one is not affected.
       //you can then handle the exception, by rethrowing the exception,in which case
       //the current transaction will also be rolled back, or continue based on your logic.
       freshTransaction.update2();
    } catch (Exception ex ) {//handle}
  }
}
```

Note that if any of the update transaction was successful, and the the parent transaction is rolled back, it will not affect the status of the 'child' transactions, as they had already been committed and their effects (if DB effects) will be committed too.

Read on Java EE Transactions [Java EE Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/transactions003.htm#BNCIJ)

Comment: I don't want to to create other class . i tried doing it by creating inner class but not working

Comment: The only way EJB will be able to manage transaction is by managing your beans. You could also inject the bean into itself (I have not tested this, but i guess it should work)

Answer (score 1):

create three different method all with TranscationAttributeType REQUIRES_NEW
Please find below code snippet for EJB3 Bean

```
public void doYourWork()
{ 
    a();
    b();
    c();

}
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void a()
{
    try
    {
        //Do the    first transaction here
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void b()
{
    try
    {
        //Do the    second transaction here
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void c()
{
    try
    {
        //Do the    third transaction here
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I created the three method but it not working at all can you show me your code how do u want me to implement it

Comment: inside catch i am throwing an exception i think due to which other two transaction are not getting executed i want to throw different message on different catch

Comment: If you use REUIRES_NEW then other two transactions will not break

Comment: i agree with you but i am throwing exception in every catch block so other two are not working...thanx for the help